# Emergency mode during startup

Tags: boot, compatibility

I install Ubuntu in my SSD and, while at first it works fine, and after a month or so some filesystem (probably root) crashes and I get the following message during boot:

**"You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type “journalctl -xb"to view system logs,
“systemctl reboot” to reboot, “systemctl default” or “exit” to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue)”.**

Pressing Ctrl-D doesn't work and I have to format my pc every time this happens. I have been advised to check if my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5480) is compatible with Ubuntu but I don't understand what that means. I would like to use Ubuntu, independent of what laptop I have.

The same laptop also has an HDD, and when I installed Ubuntu there, I also got a filesystem corruption after approximately one month.

Also, I have been told that maybe it's a boot problem, related to secure boot and that maybe changing to legacy would help, but it didn't.

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Comment: Are there any interesting output of the mentioned journalctl and systemctl commands ?

Comment: No, none of them seem to work either